# Minimum heap via array representation of a binary tree; MoveDown function loops infinitely

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-tree

I am working on implementing a minimum heap using an array datastructure, but I am having an issue with my moveDown method (used at the root node to return the collection to a heap if the root's children are every smaller than it). I assume that the reader will know a what a min heap is, but I'll describe it just in case someone does not or my understanding is incorrect.

A minimum heap (in this case) is a binary tree represented by an array such that:

1. The root node is the smallest value in the datastructure
2. A node must always be smaller than it's children
3. Given a node of array index I, it's left child will be at index I*2 + 1 and the right child at I*2 + 2

The current issue I am having is that my moveDown function runs into an infinite loop when swapping. I am having a very difficult time finding a logic error, so I fear it might be something closer to the root (pun intended, I couldn't help myself).

Notable data members of the heap.cpp file:

```
int size;
MiniVector array;// The implementing custom array
void moveDown(int root);
```

moveDown function in my heap.cpp file:

```
void BinaryHeap::moveDown( int root ){

    int temp = root;
    int tempLC = temp*2 + 1;//LeftChild
    int tempRC = temp*2 + 2;//RightChild

    //Not a leaf
    while( ( tempLC < array.size() && tempRC < array.size() )
        &&
    ( (array[temp] > array[tempLC]) || (array[temp] > array[tempRC]) ) ){

        int hold = array[temp];

        if( array[temp] > array[tempRC] ){

            array[temp] = array[tempRC];
            array[tempRC] = hold;
            temp = tempRC;
        }

        else{

            array[temp] = array[tempLC];
            array[tempLC] = hold;
            temp = tempLC;
        }

        int tempLC = temp*2 + 1;//LeftChild
        int tempRC = temp*2 + 2;//RightChild
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You redeclare your variables. At the bottom of the while loop

```
    int tempLC = temp*2 + 1;//LeftChild
    int tempRC = temp*2 + 2;//RightChild
```

should be

```
    tempLC = temp*2 + 1;//LeftChild
    tempRC = temp*2 + 2;//RightChild
```

Wouldn't happen in Java.

Also wouldn't happen if you rewrote your loop as an infinite for loop with a break in the middle

```
for (;;)
{
    int tempLC = temp*2 + 1;//LeftChild
    int tempRC = temp*2 + 2;//RightChild
    if (...)
        break;
    ...
}
```

But I get flamed whenever I suggest this kind of loop is a good idea. Last time some suggested it was 'almost an anti-pattern' and that was one of the more polite responses.

Comment: I can NOT believe I didn't notice I was re-declaring. Honestly I am completely floored I could spend so much time and not notice that.

Comment: @Joshua Sometimes you just need someone looking over your shoulder.